# How do I run this on cronjob or on Event scheduler

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I want to run this code on my cronjob! Buts its not working! Running this php every 8:00 am
I want to update the row data every day!
This is my PHP file

file path

```
/home/samplesite/public_html/profile/jobs/job1.php
```

Php

```
    <?php
        include '../database.php';
        $query = "SELECT * FROM user ";
        $rows =array();
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
        $rows[] = $row;
        }
        foreach ($rows as $row)
        {
            $id = $row['id'];
            date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
            $url = 'https://api.sample.com/'.$id;
            $ch=curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $r=curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $data = json_decode($r, true);
            $profile = $data[profile];    ?>


   <?php  $query = "UPDATE user SET (profile) VALUES ('$profile')"; ?>

            <?php } ?>
```

Cron

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/samplesite/public_html/profile/jobs/ ; php -q job1.php > /dev/null ;
```

Comment: Provide full path to your file.

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
0 0,8,16 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/samplesite/public_html/profile/jobs/job1.php
```

This cron will run at 00:00, 08:00 and 16:00 and thus entering the loop, if you have any doubts about how the cron works you can see more at [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_0,8,16_*_*_*), so you can customize the range yourself.